# How do call CAT inside a Dockerfile during the build, and have it work for any file in the image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

`cat` to standard output inside a Dockerfile is giving the following errors when building the image:

```
cat: read error: I/O error
cat: can't open '/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush': Permission denied
cat: read error: I/O error
cat: can't open '/proc/kmsg': Operation not permitted
cat: read error: Invalid argument
```

The `cat` command is being run as the last line in the Dockerfile, like this:

```
RUN find / -print -exec test -f {} \; -exec cat {} \; | wc -c
```

Note that I do not get these errors, and in fact, it works, when I do this instead,

```
RUN find . -print -exec test -f {} \; -exec cat {} \; | wc -c
```

How can this be solved to enable `cat` for any file in the image during the build?

Thanks

Comment: A container in restricted mode (which is default) *isn't supposed* to be able to muck with the kernel in ways that would impact security of the host. Which is to say -- this is a feature, not a bug. You don't want your guest to be able to flush the routing table or access kernel logs, which two of the commands you're showing would do.

Comment: (Keep in mind that a Docker container is not a virtual machine -- it's all the same kernel, even if some of the resources are namespace-restricted; the security of that kernel, then, matters a lot).

Comment: To restate/extend: `find /` is looking through the whole VFS tree, including procfs, which is a virtual filesystem that provides access to kernel settings and metadata; `find .` is searching only in your current directory (copied over from the host), staying out of the security-sensitive bits.

Comment: What you are saying is that `find / ...` is trying to access the host filesystem at secured points in the host when building the Dockerfile?

Comment: Not the host filesystem, but a virtual interface into the host kernel (which happens to be available on both the host *and* within the containers). That interface is there for good reasons; without it, processes inside the container would be unable to access metadata about the container itself and its other contents.

Comment: ("host kernel" is misleading: There's only one kernel to start with -- no separate "guest kernel" exists -- it just has different namespace handles for different parts of the process tree).

Comment: Humm .. but why does `find / ...` then works when typed at the host's console? Should not it be forbidden too?

Comment: If you aren't root, it *will* be forbidden (or if you *are* root and certain SELinux or other restrictions are in place). If you're root on the host, you're allowed to do anything on it you want.

Comment: I definitely abandoned this idea. My prefered way now is to export the entire file system of the image via `docker export` as a tar archive, and process this.